# Create a script to git pull/checkout from specific branch

Tags: git, deployment

I'm trying to write a script to deploy our webapp easily from git. We have now two servers ("production" and "development").

I've made a new `develop` branch, and after the first clone on the server the situation with `git branch -a` is this:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

I'm trying to write a simple script that will pull from master on the production server, and from develop on the development server.

After the clone I did

```
git pull origin develop
git checkout develop
```

and now the situation is this:

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

The files are matching the develop branch. So far so good.

I've tried to do the same with the master:

```
git pull origin master
git checkout master
```

and I got this message:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

and the files seems to be the same of develop.

I guess my knkowledge about git and local/remote branch is not enough, I'm missing something.

Comment: This is not really about creating a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other way around :

```
git checkout <branch>
git pull origin <branch>
```

---

Calling `git pull origin master` wil execute the following two actions :

- get the changes for remote branch `master`
  (you can achieve the same thing by running `git fetch origin master`)
- merge your *active branch* with `origin/master`
  (you can achieve the same thing by running `git merge origin/master`)

So, if your active branch was `develop`, running `git pull origin master` would move your local `develop` branch.
Then, running `git checkout master` would checkout your local `master` branch without updating it.